# making to foreign keys and converting them to one composite primary key

Tags: sql

```
create table Manager
(
    manager_id Integer(4)
        constraint manager_id_pk PRIMARY KEY(manager_id),
    DateOfBirth Integer(10),
    Salary  Integer(20),
    SEX varchar(10),
    Contact Integer(10),
);

create table Regional_Manager
(
    manager_id Integer(4)
        constraint manager_id_fk References Manager(manager_id),
    DateOfBirth Integer(10),
    Salary Integer(20),
    SEX varchar(10),
    Contact Integer(10),
    Off_Address varchar(30)
        constraint Off_Address_fk References Office(Off_Address),
    city_id integer(4)
        constraint city_id_fk References City(city_id)
);

create table Operational_Manager
(
    manager_id Integer(4)
        constraint manager_id_fk References Manager(manager_id),
    DateOfBirth Integer(10),
    Salary Integer(20),
    SEX varchar(10),
    Contact Integer(10),
    department_id Integer(4)
        constraint department_id_fk References Department(department_id),
    DateOfBirth Integer(10),
);

create table Office
(
    Off_Address varchar(30),
    num_rooms Integer(10),
    num_floors Integer(10)
    city_id Integer(10),
    manager_id Integer(4)
        constraint manager_id_fk References Manager(manager_id),
    city_id Integer(10),

    constraint city_id_fk References City(city_id),
    PRIMARY KEY(manager_id,city_id)
);
```

I'm having an issue while creating the office table. I have created to foreign keys in office table and then converted them to the composite primary key. Is that something that I can do or is there some other way to connect this table?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185513/discussion-on-question-by-asfand-shakeel-making-to-foreign-keys-and-converting-t).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it, but just keeping both fields as foreign keys is sufficient to connect to the Office table.

You should really create a separate id for the office, which will remain the same no matter the manager_id or even if the office gets moved to a nearby city/town

```
create table Office(
Off_id Integer(4), 
Off_Address varchar(30),
num_rooms Integer(10),
num_floors Integer(10)
city_id Integer(10),
manager_id Integer(4)
constraint manager_id_fk References Manager(manager_id),
city_id Integer(10),
constraint city_id_fk References City(city_id),
PRIMARY KEY(Off_id)
);
```